# Alternative to using IIF in ON clause to increase readability

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, iif

My colleague finds the use of `IIF` in the following context tricky to understand.

Is there a more readable alternative approach?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Cas;
CREATE TABLE #Cas( OP VARCHAR(10), BR  VARCHAR(10), SCORE INT)
INSERT INTO #Cas
    values
        ('A','X', 10),
        ('A','Y', 5),
        ('B','J', 6),
        ('C','Q', 50)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Target;
CREATE TABLE #Target( OP VARCHAR(10), BR  VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO #Target
    values
        ('A','ALL')

SELECT  C.OP,
        SUM(C.SCORE)
FROM    #Cas C
        INNER JOIN #Target T
            ON 
            C.OP = T.OP AND
            C.BR = IIF(T.BR = 'ALL', C.BR, T.BR)
GROUP BY C.OP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` to make it clear that either t.br is equal to ALL or is equal to c.br:

```
AND (t.br = 'ALL' or c.br = t.br)
```

or more succinctly:

```
AND t.br in ('ALL', c.br)
```

Comment: I like this better then my own answer. +1.

Comment: `AND t.br in ('ALL', c.br)` is what I'll use - much more readable

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the logical `or` operator, or even better - an `in` operator to short-hand it:

```
SELECT  C.OP,
        SUM(C.SCORE)
FROM    #Cas C
        INNER JOIN #Target T
            ON 
            C.OP = T.OP AND
            T.BR IN (C.BR, 'ALL')
GROUP BY C.OP
```

Comment: I like this better then my own answer. +1.

Comment: `T.BR IN (C.BR, 'ALL')` is what I'll use - much more readable

Answer (score 1):

[`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is syntactic sugar for `CASE`. You can write your on clause like this instead:

```
ON 
C.OP = T.OP AND
C.BR = CASE WHEN T.BR = 'ALL' THEN C.BR ELSE T.BR END
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use NULL to identify specific cases (f.e. "all"). So, code may look like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Cas( OP VARCHAR(10), BR  VARCHAR(10), SCORE INT)
INSERT INTO #Cas
    values
        ('A','X', 10),
        ('A','Y', 5),
        ('B','J', 6),
        ('C','Q', 50)


CREATE TABLE #Target( OP VARCHAR(10), BR  VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO #Target
    values
        ('A', NULL)

SELECT  C.OP,
        SUM(C.SCORE)
FROM    #Cas C
        INNER JOIN #Target T
            ON 
            C.OP = T.OP AND
            C.BR = ISNULL(T.BR, C.BR)
GROUP BY C.OP
```

Comment: we do not have NULL in the data